# Reactjs: Using same form for add and update

Tags: reactjs, redux

I crafted a reactjs crud app with help of a tutorial and it works great now. Now i am trying to merge two form together so that same form should be used for both `add` and `update` operation.

This is my `allpost.js` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Post from '../components/Post';

import EditComponent from '../components/editComponent';

class AllPost extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>All Posts</h1>
                {this.props.posts.map((post) => (
                    <div key={post.id}>
                        {post.editing ? <EditComponent post={post} key={post.id} /> :
                            <Post key={post.id} post={post} />}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        posts: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllPost);
```

and this is my postForm.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


class PostForm extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const title = this.getTitle.value;
    const message =  this.getMessage.value;
    const data = {
      id: new Date(),
      title,
      message,
      editing: false
    }
    console.log(data)
    this.props.dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_POST',
        data,
    });
    this.getTitle.value = '';
    this.getMessage.value = '';
  }
render() {
return (
<div>
  <h1>Create Post</h1>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <input required type="text" ref={(input)=>this.getTitle = input} 
    placeholder="Enter Post Title"/>
   <br /><br />
   <textarea required rows="5" ref={(input)=>this.getMessage = input} cols="28" 
    placeholder="Enter Post" />
   <br /><br />
   <button>Post</button>
  </form>
</div>
);
}
}
export default connect()(PostForm);
```

and this is my `editComponent.js` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class EditComponent extends Component {
handleEdit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newTitle = this.getTitle.value;
  const newMessage = this.getMessage.value;
  const data = {
    newTitle,
    newMessage
  }
  this.props.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE', id: this.props.post.id, data: data })
}
render() {
return (
<div>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleEdit}>
    <input required type="text" ref={(input) => this.getTitle = input}
    defaultValue={this.props.post.title} placeholder="Enter Post Title" /><br /><br />
    <textarea required rows="5" ref={(input) => this.getMessage = input}
    defaultValue={this.props.post.message} cols="28" placeholder="Enter Post" /><br /><br />
    <button>Update</button>
  </form>
</div>
);
}
}
export default connect()(EditComponent);
```

and this is my post.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Post extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{this.props.post.title}</h2>
      <p>{this.props.post.message}</p>
      <button onClick={() => this.props.dispatch({type: 'EDIT_POST', id: this.props.post.id})}>EDIT
      </button>
      <button onClick={ () => this.props.dispatch({type: 'DELETE_POST', id: this.props.post.id}) }>DELETE
      </button>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
export default connect()(Post);
```

and this is my `postReducer.js` file:

```
const postReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_POST':
        return state.concat([action.data]);
      case 'DELETE_POST':
        return state.filter((post)=>post.id !== action.id);
      case 'EDIT_POST':
        return state.map((post)=>post.id === action.id ? {...post,editing:!post.editing}:post)
      case 'UPDATE':
        return state.map((post)=>{
          if(post.id === action.id) {
            return {
               ...post,
               title:action.data.newTitle,
               message:action.data.newMessage,
               editing: !post.editing
            }
          } else return post;
        })
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
  export default postReducer;
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve this? I tried a lot to use same form form for both add and update and i failed to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own Form component with a prop of editMode to control whether it's Create or Update.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Form extends Component {
    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {editMode, post} = this.props;
        const title = this.titleRef.value;
        const body = this.bodyRef.value;
        if (editMode){
            const data = {
                title,
                body
            }
            this.props.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE', id: post.id, data})
        }
        else {
            const data = {
                id: new Date(),
                title,
                message,
                editing: false
            }
            this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_POST', data});
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {editMode, post} = this.props;
        const pageTitle = editMode ? 'Edit Post' : 'Create Post';
        const buttonTitle = editMode ? 'Update' : 'Post';
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{pageTitle}</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        required
                        type="text"
                        ref={input => this.titleRef = input}
                        placeholder="Enter Post Title"
                        defaultValue={post.title}
                    />
                    <textarea
                        required
                        rows="5"
                        ref={input => this.bodyRef = input}
                        cols="28"
                        placeholder="Enter Post"
                        defaultValue={post.body}
                    />
                    <button>{buttonTitle}</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Form.propTypes = {
    editMode: PropTypes.bool,
    post: PropTypes.object
}

Form.defaultProps = {
    editMode: false,    // false: Create mode, true: Edit mode
    post: {
        title: "",
        body: ""
    }    // Pass defined Post object in create mode in order not to get undefined objects in 'defaultValue's of inputs.
}

export default Form;
```

It would be on create mode by default but if you wanna update the post you should pass `editMode={true}` to your form component.

Answer (score 34):

I think it's better you create separate component for rendering form data(`FormComponent`) and separate components for edit(`EditComponent`) and add(`AddComponent`).

This way there will not be clutter in one component and no if/else conditions for different modes like `edit` or `add`, or in future `copy` mode.

This approach will add **flexibility** and enhances **compositional** pattern of react.

1) `AddComponent`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


class AddComponent extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (title, message) => {
    const data = {
      id: new Date(),
      title,
      message,
      editing: false
    }
    this.props.dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_POST',
        data,
    });
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Create Post</h1>
                <FormComponent
                    buttonLabel='Post'
                    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect()(AddComponent);
```

2) `EditComponent`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class EditComponent extends Component {
    handleSubmit = (newTitle, newMessage) => {
        const data = {
            newTitle,
            newMessage
        }
        this.props.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE', id: this.props.post.id, data: data })
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <FormComponent
                buttonLabel='Update'
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            />
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect()(EditComponent);
```

3) `FormComponent`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FormComponent extends Component {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const title = this.getTitle.value;
        const message =  this.getMessage.value;
        this.props.handleSubmit(title, message);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input required type="text" ref={(input) => this.getTitle = input}
                defaultValue={this.props.post.title} placeholder="Enter Post Title" /><br /><br />
                <textarea required rows="5" ref={(input) => this.getMessage = input}
                defaultValue={this.props.post.message} cols="28" placeholder="Enter Post" /><br /><br />
                <button>{this.props.buttonLabel}</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
export default FormComponent;
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Better or not better, is separate question. Author asks for solution in one component. 

There are advantages of having one component, and there is not much clutter often. You have ID -> you fill form fields and call update action, you have no ID, your form is empty, that's it. 

And additionally if edit mode is not turned on, your user see the same form but disabled.

Everything looks the same, disabled form, new form, or active form. Less things to change, less things to test.